# Is map.on('click') interfering with Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mapbox

Setup: Rails 4 + Bootstrap.  So I have a bootstrap modal embedded in the same page as a mapbox.com map I use to display data markers.

I have the following javascript code, where the console.log is working (latlng is being logged to console), but the Bootstrap modal show event is not having the window open.  Any ideas on what may be wrong?

**application.js (asset pipeline)**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**mymap.js**

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.latlng.toString());
  $('#mymodal').modal('show');
  var marker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
});
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1" id="map"></div>
</div>

<div id="#mymodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You've ID'ed the modal as `#mymodal`, change it to `mymodal` and it will work. The jQuery selector `$('#mymodal')` will start seaching for an element in DOM with the ID `mymodal` not `#mymodal`. The bracket in the selector is just for defining that you're searching for an ID.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Thanks, was having a late night and missed something I've done over and over....:)

Comment: Actually one issue, is that it's still not finding the modal - if I move the modal show action outside map.on click it works just fine...any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no, not seeing anything else in your code and your setup works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jz8sVcQpE5cFAVEf2ZcK?p=preview